# Unable to include a php file in typo3

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I am using Typo3 cms. Under the main folder I have different other folders such as typo3, typo3conf, fileadmin etc...

I have created two php files named `myphp.php`, and `myantoher.php` inside the main folder, and I used `require()` in `myphp.php`. But when that line is reached during execution, I am receiving the following errors:

> Warning: require(doc/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/domainname.com/doc/contactform.php on line 3  Fatal error:
>   require(): Failed opening required 'doc/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php'

Why am I receiving an error when I try to `require()` this file?

Comment: It may be helpful if you include the error message that you are receiving as well as the code that is generating the error.

Comment: Please find the error message.
Warning: require(doc/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/domainname.com/doc/contactform.php on line 3

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'doc/PHPMailer/class.PHPMailer.php'

Comment: Are you certain of the working directory?  Does it behave differently if you use an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: Use the TYPO3 API to run custom code. A way is to integrate a userFunc via TypoScript. Here's an example (in german) https://www.netbrothers.de/typo3-projekte/typo3-tipps/typo3-62-php-skript-einbinden/

Answer (score 2):

It's very easy to add PHP or any other files in TYPO3

You have to script

```
  includeLibs.cookie = fileadmin/cookie/cookie.php

  page.20 = USER_INT
  page.20 {
      userFunc = user_setcookie
  }
```

For more information about TYPO3 stuff you may visit my blog

https://jainishsenjaliya.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/how-to-include-custome-php-file-in-typo3/

Regards,

Jainish Senjaliya

Answer (score 0):

Here you can include your custom PHP file

**Using the CONFIG object.**

ex:

config.includeLibrary = fileadmin/templates/myscript.php

**Using the PAGE object.**

ex:

page.100.file = fileadmin/templates/myscript.php

Answer (score 0):

FYI. it's not possible to use `includeLibs` via TypoScript anymore. Instead, ensure to encapsulate code in PHP functions or PHP classes, and load them via the class loader (by putting them in a simple extension) or via Composer's autoload functionality.

You can still call functions/methods then via PHP all around TYPO3 an call them in Frontend via

```
page.10 = USER_INT
page.10.userFunc = bennis_function
```

or if it is a method in a class

```
page.10.userFunc = Benni\Mack\RandomClassName->my_method
```

If you want to do it quick and dirty, you can require your file in your `AdditionalConfiguration.php` file and use it everywhere as well.

Still, best approach is using an extension with PHP classes and PSR-4 autoloading.